# asp.net core Ajax requests gives 400 bad request but POSTMAN works

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, postman, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

I am facing trouble with ajax request in asp.net core blazor application. I have tried almost everything i can find on stackoverflow related to ajax post call results in 400 bad request
I have following controller

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}")]
    public class BoldReportsAPIController : ControllerBase, IReportController
    {
        // Report viewer requires a memory cache to store the information of consecutive client request and
        // have the rendered report viewer information in server.
        private IMemoryCache _cache;

        // IHostingEnvironment used with sample to get the application data from wwwroot.
        private IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public BoldReportsAPIController(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _cache = memoryCache;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }
// Post action to process the report from server based json parameters and send the result back to the client.
        [HttpPost]
        public object PostReportAction([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> jsonArray)
        {
            return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonArray, this, this._cache);
        }

       
    }
```

When i make request with postman it works fine as shown below.
[image: Postman call]

But when i make ajax call it gives 400 bad request error.

I have literally replaced original ajax call with the code generated from postman but that code doesn't work also.

```
 var settings = {
                    "async": true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": "https://localhost:44313/api/BoldReportsAPI/PostReportAction",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache",
                        "postman-token": "fbed680d-0143-ab86-24e6-176c16d713bf"
                    },
                    "processData": false,
                    "data": "{\"reportAction\":\"ReportLoad\",\"isReloadReport\":false,\"controlId\":\"report-viewer\",\"reportPath\":\"sales-order-detail\",\"enableVirtualEvaluation\":false,\"reportServerUrl\":\"\",\"processingMode\":\"remote\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"accessInternalValue\":false,\"customBrandSettings\":{\"hideHelpLink\":false,\"customDomain\":\"https://help.boldreports.com\",\"customBrandName\":\"Bold Reports\",\"customLinks\":[{\"name\":\"ESLicenseMessage\",\"url\":\"/licensing/license-token/\"}]}}\r\n"
                }

                $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

Comment: You should check the network request in your browser: Open developer tools > tab "Network". Now send the request and select it in dev tools. Then check the response. Asp core typically returns detailed errors that explain why this is a "bad request".

Comment: @ChristophLütjen sir it shows as follows
https://textbin.net/orp1gw2dli

The call from Postman works but i don' see any reason why its failing in network tab
https://imgur.com/a/P98rA7C

Comment: The server will send additional information in response body. To see the server response, you need to select the tab "Response" or "Preview". On the image linked in your comment, the "Headers" tab is selected and that's why you can't see the server response here.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thank you sir. I found the issue it was due to anti forgery token. I used IgnoreAntiForgeryToken and issue went away but i am not sure why it occured in first place as you can see in text file i attached the request contains the xsrf token. So if you can help regarding that i shall be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

It was due to ant forgery token. Apparently, ABP automatically adds antiforgery token so after adding

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 2000)]
```

to my action method, issue was resolved.

But it feels like I am breaking security.

Answer (score 0):

While using ValidateAntiForgeryToken, you have to add the headers for the Report Viewer API interaction. You can refer to the below article to add the headers for your Report Viewer interaction. These need to be added with the ReportViewer introp.

https://help.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/javascript-reporting/report-viewer/handle-post-actions/#add-custom-header-in-ajax-request

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for the reply but i am sending XSRF-Token in header named requestverificationtoken and it works for my application just not this controller.
You can see request headers in following image.
https://imgur.com/a/8NH9uiv